# How can i set up a point to point connection over wifi, without a router or pre existing network?

Tags: networking, wifi

Requirements are as follows:

- execute terminal commands
- transmit files

Im am using the raspberry pi 2 model B and "WiFi Dongle - Ultra Long Range High Gain w/ 5dBi Antenna" which utilises RT3070 Chipset 
http://www.modmypi.com/raspberry-pi/accessories/wifi-dongles/wifi-dongle-ultra-long-range-high-gain-w-5dbi-antenna

specs states that wifi adapter is soft AP compatible

no need for gui

Comment: Add some details about your hardware. Which pi do you have? If it's an older than rpi 3 which wifi adapter are you using? Some adapters support AP mode and adhoc mode which can help in your case

Comment: I have updated the question to reflect this info @TahirAkhtar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this link](http://elinux.org/RPi_USB_Wi-Fi_Adapters) the adpators based on RT3070 seems to support adhoc mode, so you can try your luck at setting up an adhoc wifi network between your raspberry pi and the other device (which you haven't specified in your question).

According to various resources on the internet (like [this one](http://slicepi.com/creating-an-ad-hoc-network-for-your-raspberry-pi/)), it can be done by setting `wireless-mode` to `ad-hoc` in your `/etc/network/interfaces` file, along with some other configuration.

Once you have the connection setup, the next step will be to enable ssh based login, which will allow you to execute terminal commands.

Answer (score 1):

To create an access point you can try  [`create-ap`](https://github.com/oblique/create_ap)

**Examples**

> No passphrase (open network):

```
create_ap wlan0 eth0 MyAccessPoint
```

> WPA + WPA2 passphrase:

```
create_ap wlan0 eth0 MyAccessPoint MyPassPhrase
```

> AP without Internet sharing:

```
create_ap -n wlan0 MyAccessPoint MyPassPhrase
```

> Bridged Internet sharing:

```
create_ap -m bridge wlan0 eth0 MyAccessPoint MyPassPhrase
```

> Bridged Internet sharing (pre-configured bridge interface):

```
 create_ap -m bridge wlan0 br0 MyAccessPoint MyPassPhrase
```

> Internet sharing from the same WiFi interface:

```
 create_ap wlan0 wlan0 MyAccessPoint MyPassPhrase
```

> Choose a different WiFi adapter driver

```
 create_ap --driver rtl871xdrv wlan0 eth0 MyAccessPoint MyPassPhrase
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending what you want to connect to. if its a windows machine this will work
http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/turn-windows-wifi-hotspot-share-internet-connection/

Linux(ubuntu)
https://askubuntu.com/questions/318973/how-do-i-create-a-wifi-hotspot-sharing-wireless-internet-connection-single-adap

Comment: Could you add some explanation, what happens if the link breaks in the future?